# Filter items from a list using Template Toolkit

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

How can I filter some items that are in a dynamically generated list in Template Toolkit?
I have a list of ids (also dynamically generated) and a list of ids to be excluded and I need to get just the ids that are not excluded. What the best way to do that?? 
Sample code:

```
[% SET ids = [1,2,4,10,11,12,13,17,19,20,21,50,51] %]
[% SET id_excluded = [10,11,13,20,50] %]
[% FOREACH pid IN ids %]
    [% IF ?code to filter the ids? %]
        [% pid %]
    [% END %]
[% END %]
```

Comment: Why dont you pass filtered content to Template?

Comment: I am actually doing this now but my first though was to filter in the template, and in Perl its so easy to do that using the smart match operator (~~) and I was surprised that in TT it isnt that easy. I tried to search for a answer and didnt find so asked here.

Comment: The current version of TT in general use (2.x) pre-dates perl 5.10, when the smart-match operator was introduced. One would generally have used a grep {} construction in pre-smart-match perl as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `grep` VMethod for lists, eg:

```
[% SET ids = [1,2,4,10,11,12,13,17,19,20,21,50,51] %]
[% SET id_excluded = [10,11,13,20,50] %]
[% FOREACH pid IN ids %]
    [% UNLESS id_excluded.grep("^$pid\$").size %]
        [% pid %]
    [% END %]
[% END %]
```

Which produces the following:

```
1 2 4 12 17 19 21 51
```